# Reading every N bytes of a file in Python

Tags: python, io, binaryfiles, unpack

I have a large Fortran binary file that contains many records (a record is a call to a `write` function in Fortran). Each record contains 4 floats. The first three floats represent the `x,y,z` coordinate of a particle and the last float represents the time.
The way this file was written wraps each record by two integers. So overall, each record including the wrapper has 24 bytes.
I am trying to write a Python script that reads only the `z` coordinate in each record. For this, I need to read bytes 12-16, 36-40 and so on.

So I tried the following

```
import struct
import numpy as np

def read_field(fin):
    field_offset = 8 #Offset of the first byte of the z coordinate WITHIN a record
    field_type = 'f' #A float
    field_dtype = np.dtype('>'+_field_type) #Numpy dtype
    field_data = np.empty(num_of_records,dtype=field_dtype) #num_of_records is a global variable, equal to file size divided by record size
    field_size = 4 #Bytes in a float
    record_size = 24 #Number of bytes in a record INCLUDING the wrapper
    
    fin.seek(0) #go to the beginning of the file
    fin.seek(4) #First 4 bytes are the wrapper of the first record
    fin.seek(field_offset,1) #Go to the beginning of the z coordinate
    for i in range(num_of_records):
        field_data[i], = struct.unpack('>'+field_type,fin.read(field_size)) #Unpack the bytes of the float
        fin.seek(record_size-field_size,1) #Go to the beginning of the next z coordinate
    return field_data
```

This seems to do the job, however EXTREMELY slowly as compared to reading the entire file using `np.fromfile`. I could settle with the latter, however my files are huge and loading all of them would be extremely memory inefficient.

Is there a faster way I could accomplish this?

Comment: `np.fromfile()` is probably written in highly optimized C code, you're not likely to be able to achieve similar performance in a Python loop.

Comment: You can replace the first 3 seek calls with `fin.seek(4 + field_offset)`. But since this isn't in the loop it will have negligible performance impact.

Comment: @Barmar do you think using `numba` would have any effect here?

Comment: @MattDMo probably not much, the slowness here is almost certainly due to `struct.unpack`

Comment: Sadly numba does not support I/O operations AFAIK